# React Js does not get images after hosting on netlify

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku

I am hosting React app on Netlify and NodeJs server on Heroku.

The image is hosted on the server directory, in an "image" folder..

```
     // Build the image path
        const file = req.file ? 
        req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/' + req.file.path 
        : null;
```

The code above is building the image link which will be stored in the database and will be looking like "https://home-renter.heroku.com/images/1663093729973.jpg". Normally, if I paste the link on the browser, the server should send the image...
But in this case I get 404 error....
The image link is saved into the mongodb as
[image]

In the chrome console I have the following errors and warnings:
[image]

I do not know what should I look for. I dont have a starting point...

Update. If I add a house, and upload images, the image selection works. However if I refresh the page, the website crashes and send 404...

```
// Static files
const path = require('path')
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));


app.get('/', (req, res, next) => res.send('Wellcome to home renter'));
```

***Update***

The problem was while I was deleting the images from the post. I was splitting the image link from 3000 (port) instead of the new URL.

Comment: Do these links work? So if you copy it to a browser do you get a 404 or the image?

Comment: None of those links works. Not in the browser, and not in React js. It works only in the local development

Comment: If I copy the link and paste in the browser, I get the 404 error

Comment: I used this as a static file ```
const path = require('path')
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')));```

Comment: Where have you wrote this `app.use` command? Can you share some more context?

Comment: I edited the the question. The app.use is used to set the static files.

Comment: Seems like it don't find your images folder on the server. Is it uploaded to the environment, too?

Comment: I do not use dotenv.

Comment: Sorry if I have confused you. With environment I mean the server were you run the application. Is the images folder existent there?

Comment: yes. I am 90% sure that it is. Because I uploaded to github first and after I linked the github repo to heroku.

Comment: https://github.com/ddmihai/Home-renter-backend

Comment: https://main--home-renter.netlify.app/

If you could add a house, and after delete it. It crashes all the website and the server.

Comment: I don't see any of the files your backend returns in the images folder of your repository.

Comment: I am sorry. I think I am not understanding you. I quite new to this. The images should go straight into the Images folder. There are no other folders inside the Images one

Comment: Ah okay. After creating a house it works as intended. The image is accessible.
I think your problem is, that you added the house locally and not uploaded the image correctly to the server.

Comment: Note that your images are stored on the server by heroku.app. I think that uploaded images are lost if you redeploy. Maybe you should save them to a persistent datastore (directly to your db, if you are willing to accept the performance penalty, or to a S3-like storage). It will not sync your uploaded images back to your GitHub repository.

Comment: Thank you. I thought is possible.

Comment: module.exports = {
    deleteImage: (imageLink) => {
        const link = imageLink.split(3000)[1];
        console.log(imageLink);
        console.log(link);
        fs.unlinkSync('.' + link);
    }
}

Comment: This throws an error to the heroku dashboard if you delete the house

Comment: You should definitely change your image-store ;)

Comment: I found the problem.. I will update the question. I will also take in consideration the S3 image buckets. Thank you